# itertools cycle() does not seem to take a starting index. What's a good way to get cycle to start at an arbitrary index other than 0?

Tags: python, python-itertools

Python's `itertools cycle()` does not seem to take a starting index. What's the best way to get `cycle()` to start at an arbitrary position in the sequence other than 0, whilst of course ensuring the cycle iterates through all of the sequence's elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to move to the position you want to start from:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = islice(cycle(l), 2, None)

[next(c) for i in range(10)]
# [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Another option is to just prepend your cycle with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = chain(l[2:], cycle(l))

[next(c) for i in range(10)]
# [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```